# Multiplying a homogeneous linear system with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let A and B be m x n and n x p matrices respectively.
>
> Suppose the homogeneous linear system $ Bx = 0 $ has infinitely many
>   solutions. How many solutions does the system $ ABx = 0 $ have?

From what I know, infinitely many solutions mean that there is at least one non-pivot column in the row-echleon form of a matrix. Let's say we define the following:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} \\
B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \\
AB = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a & a \\ c & c\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am unable to see from this form whether the operation actually alters the number of solutions for the system. Is anyone able to advise me please?

Comment: Have you tried putting the matrix in row echelon form?

Comment: In the problem, I am not given an actual matrix. But I just defined an example matrix to try to see a relationship. The example matrix given for $ B $ above is in row echelon form.

Comment: No, the row echelon form for $AB$ is the question.

Comment: I am not given the matrix $AB$ either

Comment: When I said the matrix, I wasn't clear, but I meant the product matrix.

Comment: Since I only have variables to represent the values for $AB$, how do I put it in row-echelon form?

Comment: What do you know about the rank of a product of matrices?

Comment: I wasn't taught about rank.